# Sort by name and join in Dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I got some data-base and then converted it to pandas DataFrame like this

```
        food_weight = pd.DataFrame(L, columns=['Week day', 'Date', 'Time','Type',
                                     'Favourites', 'Weight'])
```

lets print it:

```
    Week day  Date        Time   Type      Favourites        Weight
0   Thursday  04-09-2020  14:55  lunch      dish1            200
1   Thursday  04-09-2020  15:17  snack      dish2            100
2   Thursday  04-09-2020  15:17  snack      dish3            130
3   Thursday  04-09-2020  19:17  dinner     dish4            115
4   Monday    04-06-2020  17:41  snack           ----etc-----                       
5   Monday    04-06-2020  17:46  breakfast                            
6   Monday    04-06-2020  17:46  lunch                        
7   Monday    04-06-2020  17:46  snack                                       
8   Tuesday   04-07-2020  17:57  snack                       
9   Tuesday   04-07-2020  17:57  snack                                       
10  Wednesday 04-08-2020  17:57  snack                                 
11  Friday    04-10-2020  17:57  snack                                   
12  Saturday  04-11-2020  17:57  snack  
13  Sunday    04-12-2020  17:57  snack                              
14  Saturday  11-04-2020  18:06  snack                
15  Saturday  11-04-2020  18:06  lunch
```

i'd tried to use `food_weight.groupby(['Week day','Date','Type','Time'])['Favourites'].apply(lambda tags: ','.join(tags))` and got this:

```
    Week day  Date        Type   Time         Favourites
0   Thursday  04-09-2020  lunch  14:55        dish1 
                          snach  15:17        dish2,dish3
                          dinner 19:17        dish4
```

but i need to receive smth like this :(

```
    Week day  Date        Type   Time         Favourites       Weight
0   Thursday  04-09-2020  lunch  14:55        dish1            200
                          snach  15:17        dish2,dish3      100,130
                          dinner 19:17        dish4            115                            
                                                 ----etc-----
```

[Data-base on GitHub](https://github.com/artisakov/vigilant-journey/blob/master/app/diacompanion.db)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC:

```
food_weight.groupby(['Week day','Date','Type','Time']).agg({"Favourites": lambda tags: ','.join(tags),
                    "Weight": lambda tags: ','.join(tags)})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pandas.pivot_table`:

```py
# prerequisite, since you can only join strings

food_weight[['Favourites', 'Weight']]=food_weight[['Favourites', 'Weight']].astype(str)

res=food_weight.pivot_table(index=['Week day','Date','Type','Time'], values=['Favourites', 'Weight'], aggfunc=', '.join)
```

Outputs:

```py
>>> res
                                    Favourites    Weight
Week day Date       Type   Time
Thursday 04-09-2020 dinner 19:17         dish4       115
                    lunch  14:55         dish1       200
                    snack  15:17  dish2, dish3  100, 130
```

Ref. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html